# New Relic: get alerts on 500 error?

Tags: django, newrelic

I am running a Django 1.8 with CloudFlare in front. I've added New Relic via CloudFlare (i.e. I'm running New Relic via a JavaScript injection, I guess).

Is it possible to set up alerts in New Relic to get emails whenever a user hits a 500 error on my site?

I know [Django can send error reports itself,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/error-reporting/) but it would be a lot easier if a third-party app could do it for me - I really don't like putting email passwords in settings files.

Comment: I think this should be in the new relic forum or product support, it is not a matter of implementing new relic or django code. Nevertheless, what is the matter with keeping a disctinct email account for that matter and have a password in the settings? There are so many other settings in there such as db credentials and secret key that an email password is not a big deal, esp. if the account is distinct as I said.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll set up a new gmail account for this purpose. Just didn't like the idea of including the password for an account that was used for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

We have pretty much similar setup with nginx as frontend and uWSGI + django as a backend.  We're using [nginx plugin](https://newrelic.com/plugins/nginx-inc/13) for Newrelic to create an alert for the number of 5xx requests.

Comment: FYI, the link points to your account's plugin directory and is not available to be seen by public..